# Merging single bands into one multiband file in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, google-earth-engine

I am a GIS beginner level user and I have used the following GEE script: https://github.com/MarcYin/SIAC_GEE

In order to perform atmospheric correction to get Sentinel-2 L2A level from the Sentinel-2 L1C images (as the L2A images have tremendous cloud percentage for the period of time that interests me). The resulting files are split into 10m, 20m and 60m resolution bands.
Then I am trying to add it band by band in ArcMap in order to create a multiband image via Composite Bands tool. It does work indeed however the tool seems to resample all the bands to 60m resolution and I lose image quality doing that. Is there any way to keep the original Sentinel-2 bands resolution while merging the bands?

Comment: I don't believe, but I may be wrong, that multi-band rasters support different cell sizes for each band. I've certainly never come across this scenario in my career but then again I'm not a remote sensing specialist.

Comment: You can't have *bands* of differing resolution. You'd have to oversample to make them all the same (they also need to be aligned center-center)